# Multilingual Bibliography with name-year style

Tags: bibliographies

I would like to write a greek text with references both in English and in Greek and I would like to compile it with pdfLatex. I've tried using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\begin{document} 
\gr 
Όπως έχει αναφερθεί στην Ελληνική \citep{Sfa04}
αλλά και τη διεθνή \citep{Miranda02} βιβλιογραφία 

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{test} 


\end{document}
```

And the test.bib file is:

```
@book{Miranda02,
 language = {english},
 author = {M. J. Miranda and P. L. Fackler},
 publisher = {MIT Press},
 title = {Applied Computational Economics and Finance},
 year = {2002}
}

@book{Sfa04,
 language = {greek},
 author = {Μ. Σφακιανάκης},
 publisher = {Εκδόσεις Πατάκη},
 title = {Προσομοίωση και εφαρμογές},
 year = {2004}
}
```

And it runs perfectly. My problem is that I'd like to have citations like (Author's Name, year) and both English and Greek references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use biblatex + biber. It has excellent support for various languages. You will have to set the language in the bib with the langid field:

```
@book{Miranda02,
 language = {english},
 langid = {english},
 author = {M. J. Miranda and P. L. Fackler},
 publisher = {MIT Press},
 title = {Applied Computational Economics and Finance},
 year = {2002}
}

@book{Sfa04,
 language = {greek},
 langid={greek},
 author = {Μ. Σφακιανάκης},
 publisher = {Εκδόσεις Πατάκη},
 title = {Προσομοίωση και εφαρμογές},
 year = {2004}
}
```

Then this will work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib,autolang=other,language=auto]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
\gr
Όπως έχει αναφερθεί στην Ελληνική \citep{Sfa04}
αλλά και τη διεθνή \citep{Miranda02} βιβλιογραφία

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do I use biblatex + biber?