# reduce spacing before and after citation

Tags: spacing, biblatex, citing

Having used [these instructions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241352/multilingual-bibliography-with-name-year-style) I saw a problem. When I use the `\citep` command I take:

> ( name, date )

Instead of:

> (name, date)

What's my problem?

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib,autolang=other,language=auto, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,patterns,pgfplots.fillbetween}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\arraybackslash}m{5cm}}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{bchart}



\author{Γαλανάκης Γιάννης}
\title{Διπλωματική Εργασία \\ \textlatin{1$^{st}$ preliminary draft}}
\date{\today}

\addto\captionsgreek{%
  \renewcommand\appendixpagename{Παραρτήματα}
\renewcommand\appendixtocname{Παράρτημα}
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection.\ #1}{}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\slshape \leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\usepackage{etoolbox}


\begin{document}
\maketitle



\chapter{Εισαγωγή}



 Η επένδυση στην εκπαίδευση θα μπορούσε να συμβάλλει στην οικονομική ανάπτυξη, μέσω της αποδοτικότερης αξιοποίησης των ανθρωπίνων δεξιοτήτων και ικανοτήτων. Οι περισσότερες μελέτες κατέληξαν στο συμπέρασμα ότι η βελτίωση του μορφωτικού επιπέδου μιας κοινωνίας σχετίζεται θετικά με την οικονομική ανάπτυξη, ιδιαίτερα σε χώρες με χαμηλό επίπεδο εκπαίδευσης ή με χαμηλό εισόδημα\footnote{Η εκπαίδευση δεν φέρνει μόνο στα μορφωμένα άτομα μεγαλύτερες αποδόσεις αλλά και στο σύνολο της κοινωνίας, αυξάνοντας τον ρυθμό αύξησης του ΑΕΠ διαχρονικά, το ΑΕΠ ανά κεφαλή και γενικότερα το επίπεδο διαβίωσης.} \citep{woodhall2004cost}. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried the minimal example by Ulrike in the thread you mention and get no spacing problem. A minimal example showing the issue is needed.

Comment: @egreg I've updated my answer with a minimal example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding spaces every time a language is changed:

```
\addto\captionsgreek{%
  \renewcommand\appendixpagename{Παραρτήματα}% <------
  \renewcommand\appendixtocname{Παράρτημα}% <-------
}
```

Some advice for your document:

1. `hyperref` should be loaded last, with the `unicode` option:

   ```
   \usepackage{bchart}
   \usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
   ```
2. `latexsym` should not be loaded; if you need the symbol it provides, load `amssymb` instead (which you already do)
3. Add `\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}` to your preamble, or the page headers would be misplaced